permutation test in edgeR
I have a simple RNA-seq experiment with treatment and control, each with 3 biological repeats. I run my data through edgeR and obtained differentially expressed genes (DEGs). Due to the low sample number and small effect size, there are likely more genes affected by the treatment that didn't meet the cutoff. For that reason, I want to try extracting more information from my data using a permutation test. I resampled my data by shuffling the columns and generated 1000 permuted dataframes. Next, I run each dataframe through my edgeR pipeline, which produced results such as RowName, logFC, logCPM, LR, and PValue. My qustion is, Which value (for example, logFC or PValue) do I take from each permuted dataframe to generate the distribution for each gene and calculate the p-value? Also, what is the p-value calculation?
Thank you!

(This question suites better https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/). edgeR is a very solid package that was designed to make the best of few replicates so I don't think you can easily improve on that. Regarding the permutation, if you have only few samples there aren't many combinations you can generate so I'm not sure how sensible it is to go that route.

thank you! I reposted my question in https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/

Most of the 'magic' in edgeR lies in its normalization and mean-variance shrinkage before running a negative binomial GLM, all of which you have presumably replicated across permutations. Producing a P-value happens via a likelihood ratio test (or its "exact" equivalent), though there's no reason why a permutation wouldn't be valid as well. It remains to be seen how powerful such test might be, because resampling obviously also relies on your original sample size (with $n=6$ you can easily enumerate the permutations exhaustively). Edit: in hindsight that last point should really make you reconsider the approach, because you only have ${6\choose 3}=20$ total permutations, so the granularity in your resampled P-value will be 0.05 before any multiplicity.
The key idea behind a permutation test is to scramble your group allocation, re-calculate your test statistic, and determine how often you observe a result as extreme (get a statistic as large) as your actual sample. In your case this test statistic would be the log fold change between groups (logFC). The other statistics -- logCPM is the average expression in counts per million, LR the likelihood ratio, and PValue its P-value -- are either not directly relevant to your comparison of interest or are part of the default, non-permuted test.
Let's go over a simple two-group example using some simulated data:
ngenes <- 30     ## Need some dimensionality for most of edgeR to work
nsamples <- 10

group <- rep(0:1, each=nsamples)
ngroups <- length(unique(group))

set.seed(1)
counts <- matrix(
  rnbinom(ngroups*nsamples*ngenes, mu=500, size=10),
  ncol = ngroups*nsamples, nrow = ngenes
)

## Gene #1 is 2-fold DE for Group == 1, all others the same
counts[1,] <- round(2**(log2(counts[1,]) + group))

We now need the relevant statistic both in the original sample and in the permutations that will follow. I don't know what your pipeline looks like exactly but it might be something like:
## Calculate log FC for a given group allocation
exact_test <- function(g, c = counts) {
  fit <- edgeR::DGEList(c, group = g) |>
    edgeR::calcNormFactors() |>
    (\(y) suppressMessages(edgeR::estimateDisp(y)))() |>
    edgeR::exactTest()
  
  fit$table$logFC
}

## Original sample result
fc0 <- exact_test(group)
#> 0.93791024 -0.08641194  0.23070125 ...

Now all that's left is to generate the permutations, retrieve the same statistics, and then determine in how many resamples the statistic exceeds the original one. I'm doing the latter on the absolute value to produce a two-sided test:
resamples <- 1E3
fc <- vapply(seq_len(resamples), \(.) {
  exact_test(sample(group))
}, numeric(nrow(counts)))

pval <- vapply(seq_along(fc0), \(i) {
  mean(abs(fc[i,]) >= abs(fc0[i]))
}, numeric(1))

#> 0.000 0.645 0.236 ...

In this example, none of the permutations exceeded the log fold change of the first gene in the original sample (although 1,000 resamples really isn't that many -- using ten times that gives $P=0.0003$). This can directly be interpreted as how likely your data were under a null hypothesis of exchangeable groups, so that's your P-value. Because you will be producing as many of those as you have genes it's probably a good idea to include some kind of multiplicity adjustment here too.

Thank you for your detailed response!. I have a following question. From my understanding, the logFC represents the effect size, but the p-value encompasses both the effect size and variance. So, wouldn't the p-value be a better test statistic to determine if the original dataframe best shows DEG compared to permuted dataframes? Additionally, could you please provide a more detailed explanation of your Edit?

The sampling variability also enters into the permutation through its resampling -- the more variable the sample the more likely the resampled statistic will be different from the original. I'm not sure what the implications would be of trying to recombine permuted LRT P-values, they come with some additional assumptions & you can't really just average them, they carry no information on the magnitude of an effect.

Expanding on the sample size; with just 6 samples across 2 groups there isn't a lot to permute -- only 20 unique conformations are possible. Each of these will have a unique outcome, either better (the same) or not than the original. The permutation P-value counts those unique outcomes, so with 20 possibilities it can only ever move in increments of 0.05 (1/20). This results in a very insensitive test, because the resampling space is so small that you could easily do it by hand.

ok, i understand thank you!!

Two quick points about permutations. First, one needs to include the original data as a case when computing the permutation p-value, see https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.05766. Should never get an exact zero p-value. Second, permutation tests assume that the samples are iid under the null hypothesis. That will not be the case for RNA-seq if the sequencing depth differs between samples.
